# chmod 777 no effects on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, mount, chmod

I'm trying to assign run privileges to a file named foobar using:

```
sudo chmod 777 foobar
```

However nothing happens.
The file is located on a NTFS mounted partition.
The mount command says:

```
/dev/sda4 on /media/DATA type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

The command

```
ls -l foobar
```

run after chmod says:

```
-rw------- 1 myusername myusername 2261603 Aug 29 17:54 foobar
```

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Also, you could try running "sudo chmod a+x foobar" just to see if you get a different result, though I doubt you would.

Comment: Linux permissions don't work right on NTFS volumes mounted via fuse. you have to set the access modifiers in the fstab or the mount command. see the fuse options here: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/fuse.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NTFS does not handle file permissions in the same was as Linux, as explained in the [`ntfs-3g` FAQ](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#permissions):

> Why have chmod and chown no effect? [sic]
>
> By default files on NTFS are owned by root with full access to
>   everyone. To get standard per-file protection you should mount with
>   the “permissions” option. Moreover, if you want the permissions to be
>   interoperable with a specific Windows configuration, you have to map
>   the users.

So, either modify your `/etc/fstab` with the appropriate options: (I changed `default_permissions` to `permissions`):

```
/dev/sda4 /media/DATA ntfs rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,permissions,blksize=4096
```

or, just unmount and remount manually:

```
sudo umount /media/DATA
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,permissions /dev/sda4 /media/DATA
```

You should now be able to change permissions normally with `sudo chmod`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can I mount it automatically using your command as the system boots?

Comment: @HAL9000 yes, modify `/etc/fstab` as I have shown in my answer and next time you reboot, it will be mounted with the right options.

Comment: should I only append that line in /etc/fstab? Or should I do something other? I was trying to read some tutorials but I don't know what UUID is

Comment: a UUID is a name for your device, just like '\dev\sda1'. you can find your uuid from a terminal with 'ls -a /dev/disk/by-uuid'

Comment: I simply appended that line in /etc/fstab and it works. However now all the files on the drive are flagged as executable

Comment: @HAL9000 OK, but make sure you don't have two entries mounting the same disk in `fstab`.  And yes, I think that the only way to do this is having all files marked as executable but that should not be a problem since NTFS partitions should never be used as a main working partition in Linux.