# Reduce the permission of a file in linux

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, psql

psql -h 127.0.0.1 throwing this error : 
**.pgpass** has group or world access; permissions should be u=rw (0600) or less 
How do I reduce the permissions currently it shows : -rwxrwxrwx

Comment: What is the filesystem? Example problem: [NTFS does not handle file permissions in the same was as Linux](https://superuser.com/a/638339/432690).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chmod` for that. You can either use the numeric form, `chmod 600`, or the symbolic form, `chmod o-rwx`.

Comment: I did `chmod 660 .pgpass`. But still it shows `-rwxrwxrwx` in permissions for this file

Comment: Is it a symlink? Did the command give an error? Where is the file?

Comment: No it's not a symlink. I just created this file. Is there any way to debug this

Comment: Where is the file stored?

Comment: in the current directory where I am working. It's a custom directory

Comment: The only reason I can think of for a file not to change its permissions is if it is on a filesystem that doesn't support that

Comment: could it be because I am using WSL ubuntu

Comment: Yes. Try to create the file "on the Linux side"